# (React) Bootstrap sobrescrevendo meu css

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, react

Olá, pessoal. Eu sou iniciante com react e eu estava desenvolvendo uma aplicação front-end e decidi usar o bootstrap pra fazer um slide. Instalei o bootstrap através do npm install e ainda instalei o jquery e o popper.js para poder usar os elementos com javascript. Porém o bootstrap está sobrescrevendo o meu css, não importa a ordem em que eu importo as coisas, continua sobrescrevendo. A importação está assim:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';

import './carousel-style.scss';
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você está importando o seu css depois do bootstrap? (no código não vejo o seu css). E isso ocorre apenas em produção (depois de você usar o `npm run build`) ou em desenvolvimento também ( `npm start`)? Está usando `React.Lazy` e `React.Suspense` em algum lugar do app?

Comment: Editei meu trecho de código pra melhor visualização. Sim, estou importando meu css por último e isso ta acontecendo no desenvolvimento, no momento não estou fazendo deploy. Não estou usando nem React.Lazy nem React.Suspense.

Comment: Ok. Você pode compartilhar também o código de CSS que está sendo sobrescrito e a interpretação no navegador, mostrando o que substituiu esse CSS? Talvez o HTML referente ao `carousel` ou o retorno do `.jsx` ajude a entender melhor o problema também

Comment: Ah, esqueci de comentar que no momento essas importações estavam no **carousel.js** e estavam alterando vários elementos do **index.js** que é onde eu estou importando o slide. Tentei colocar as importações no **index.js** antes do css do index, porém continuou da mesma forma.

Answer (score 0):

Estas libs não são orientadas a componentes, logo você deve chamar ela uma unica vez no arquivo main de seu webpack. Normalmente este arquivo seria o app.js.